# how to set json validator globally to check the Content Type of request that it must be json in wso2 if not 415 Unsupported Media Type as status code

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am using wso2 API manager 3.2.0 .I want to check incoming requests Content Type that it only allowed to be application/json if any other type sent as content type for example application/xml ,415 Unsupported Media Type as must be show as status code for all resources in a rest API.how can I do this.for example I sent following request and recieve 500 internal server error , my goal is to check content type and if content type was not application/json , statu code 415 Unsupported Media Type show to client as response :

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://10.10.10.24:8243/pri/general/v1/service1' \
--data ''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [Custom Mediation Policy](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/learn/api-gateway/message-mediation/changing-the-default-mediation-flow-of-api-requests/#creating-per-api-mediation-policies) and engage the following logic.

```xml
<filter regex="application/json" source="$trp:Content-Type">
    <then>
    </then>
    <else>
      <property value="415" name="HTTP_SC" scope="axis2"/>
      <respond/>
    </else>
</filter>
```