# how to handle <am:code>601000</am:code>error in wso2 api manager when body type is different from content type?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I want to write a sequence that returns a custom error response with a 415 status code ("Unsupported Media Type") if the content type header in the request does not match the actual request body type.
when I send a request to wso2 API gateway for example :

```
 curl --location 'Https://api.llc.com/pri/sample/v1/activate' \
 --header 'Content-Type: text/csv' \
 --header 'Cookie: cookiesession1=2A041602IQFLPJ3ARNRIM9OLFBHS0DA6' \
 --data '{
 "Code": "6901",
 "clientAddress": "122.12.44.255",
 "channel": "WEB",
  }'
```

when content type in header set to text/cs for example and I send json in body I got this error :

```
<am:fault xmlns:am="http://wso2.org/apimanager">
<am:code>601000</am:code>
<am:type>Status report</am:type>
<am:message>Runtime Error</am:message>
<am:description>Error while building message. Error while building Passthrough 
stream</am:description>
</am:fault>
```

how to handle this type of error(customize this error and send unsupported media type with 415 error code because I want to only support json as body) ?
here is the error I got in wso2 carbon log :

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-24 12:04:52,091] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils} - Error while building Passthrough stream org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '{' (code 123) in prolog
; expected '<'
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMDocumentImpl.getOMDocumentElement(OMDocumentImpl.java:109)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:570)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:566)
        at org.apache.axis2.builder.ApplicationXMLBuilder.processDocument(ApplicationXMLBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.DeferredMessageBuilder.getDocument(DeferredMessageBuilder.java:153)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:169)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:122)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.buildMessage(AbstractListMediator.java:152)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:95)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:71)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler.mediate_aroundBody0(APIManagerExtensionHandler.java:65)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler.mediate(APIManagerExtensionHandler.java:58)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler.handleRequest_aroundBody2(APIManagerExtensionHandler.java:90)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler.handleRequest(APIManagerExtensionHandler.java:79)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:373)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.apiProcessNonDefaultStrategy(RESTRequestHandler.java:144)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.identifyAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:164)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:95)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:73)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:331)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:99)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:367)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:426)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:181)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '{' (code 123) in prolog; expected '<'
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedChar(StreamScanner.java:639)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:2052)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1134)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.next(DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.java:34)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214)
        ... 30 more
        
        TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-24 12:04:52,094] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator} - {api:admin--private-card:vv1} Error while building message. Error while building Passthrough stream org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error while building Passthrough stream
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.handleException(RelayUtils.java:452)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:215)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:122)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.buildMessage(AbstractListMediator.java:152)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:95)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:71)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler.mediate_aroundBody0(APIManagerExtensionHandler.java:65)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler.mediate(APIManagerExtensionHandler.java:58)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler.handleRequest_aroundBody2(APIManagerExtensionHandler.java:90)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler.handleRequest(APIManagerExtensionHandler.java:79)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:373)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.apiProcessNonDefaultStrategy(RESTRequestHandler.java:144)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.identifyAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:164)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:95)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:73)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:331)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:99)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:367)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:426)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:181)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '{' (code 123) in prolog; expected '<'
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMDocumentImpl.getOMDocumentElement(OMDocumentImpl.java:109)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:570)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:566)
        at org.apache.axis2.builder.ApplicationXMLBuilder.processDocument(ApplicationXMLBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.DeferredMessageBuilder.getDocument(DeferredMessageBuilder.java:153)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:169)
        ... 24 more
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '{' (code 123) in prolog; expected '<'
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedChar(StreamScanner.java:639)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:2052)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1134)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.next(DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.java:34)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214)
        ... 30 more
        
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-24 12:04:52,095] ERROR {API_LOGGER.admin--private-card} - Error while building message. Error while building Passthrough stream org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error while building Passthrough stream
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.handleException(RelayUtils.java:452)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:215)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:122)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.buildMessage(AbstractListMediator.java:152)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:95)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:71)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler.mediate_aroundBody0(APIManagerExtensionHandler.java:65)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler.mediate(APIManagerExtensionHandler.java:58)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler.handleRequest_aroundBody2(APIManagerExtensionHandler.java:90)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler.handleRequest(APIManagerExtensionHandler.java:79)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:373)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.apiProcessNonDefaultStrategy(RESTRequestHandler.java:144)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.identifyAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:164)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:95)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:73)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:331)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:99)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:367)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:426)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:181)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '{' (code 123) in prolog; expected '<'
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMDocumentImpl.getOMDocumentElement(OMDocumentImpl.java:109)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:570)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:566)
        at org.apache.axis2.builder.ApplicationXMLBuilder.processDocument(ApplicationXMLBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.DeferredMessageBuilder.getDocument(DeferredMessageBuilder.java:153)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:169)
        ... 24 more
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '{' (code 123) in prolog; expected '<'
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedChar(StreamScanner.java:639)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:2052)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1134)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.next(DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.java:34)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214)
        ... 30 more

TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-24 12:04:52,113]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - {api:admin--private-card:vv1} STATUS = Executing default 'fault' sequence, ERROR_CODE = 601000, ERROR_MESSAGE = Error while building message. Error while building Passth
rough stream
```

Comment: Do you have any custom mediation policies that build the message(Work with the request body)? Also, share the full stack trace you see in the wso2carbon.log.

Comment: I don't have any related custom mediation policy,I added wso2 carbon logs to question

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why your message is being built. But you are seeing this error because you don't have a message builder configured for content type `text/csv`. Hence add the following to your deployment.toml and then you should be able to use the mediation policy that you used in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76028549/2627018) question.

```ini
[[custom_message_builders]]
content_type = "text/csv"
class="org.apache.axis2.format.PlainTextBuilder"
```

Comment: I use custom mediation policy that you mentioned in this question(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76027829/how-to-set-json-validator-globally-to-check-the-content-type-of-request-that-it) , is it the probable reason for this error ?

Comment: @Alifarahzadi No if you just have the logic in the answer, It will not. Unless you have additional mediators added like logs.

Comment: actually this happens when the content type header in the request does not match the actual request body type,I mean for all content types , how can I handle it globally?

Comment: @Alifarahzadi adding the above doesn't solve your issue?

Comment: the request just timeout

Comment: @Alifarahzadi do you see any errors?

Comment: TID: [-1] [] [2023-04-25 17:13:43,998]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - {api} STATUS = Executing default 'fault' sequence, ERROR_CODE = 101504, ERROR_MESSAGE = Send timeout

Comment: @Alifarahzadi that means the server was unable to send the request to the backend. So the content type validation sequence didn't engage.

Comment: how to solve the problem in this case?

Comment: @Alifarahzadi You may have to add few logs to the mediation sequence and see what's going on.